# SQL: How do I select all of a column that have at least 2 of another column of a specific value? [using mariadb]

Tags: sql, group-by, mariadb, where-clause, having-clause

So I have a table like this and have been trying to figure out a way to SELECT all hotelNo that have > 1 type='double' room. Haven't been able to figure out a way help would be appreciated.

```
MariaDB [hotel]> SELECT * FROM room;

+--------+---------+--------+-------+
| roomNo | hotelNo | type   | price |
+--------+---------+--------+-------+
|      1 |       1 | single |    80 |
|      1 |       2 | single |    90 |
|      1 |       3 | single |    80 |
|      1 |       4 | single |    80 |
|      1 |       5 | single |    80 |
|      1 |       6 | double |   100 |
|      1 |       7 | single |    80 |
|      2 |       1 | single |    80 |
|      2 |       2 | single |    80 |
|      2 |       3 | single |    80 |
|      2 |       4 | single |    80 |
|      2 |       5 | single |    80 |
|      2 |       6 | single |    80 |
|      2 |       7 | single |    80 |
|      3 |       1 | double |    95 |
|      3 |       2 | double |   100 |
|      3 |       3 | double |    95 |
|      3 |       4 | double |    95 |
|      3 |       5 | double |    95 |
|      3 |       7 | double |    95 |
|      4 |       1 | vip    |   120 |
|      4 |       2 | vip    |   120 |
|      4 |       3 | vip    |   120 |
|      4 |       4 | vip    |   120 |
|      4 |       5 | double |   100 |
|      5 |       1 | single |    85 |
|      5 |       2 | other  |   120 |
|      5 |       3 | other  |   110 |
|      5 |       4 | double |    95 |
|      5 |       5 | double |   100 |
+--------+---------+--------+-------+
```

30 rows in set (0.001 sec)

I had:

```
MariaDB [hotel]> SELECT hotelNo, type, COUNT(*) FROM room GROUP BY type HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```

But that just gives me the total number of each room type:

```
+---------+--------+----------+
| hotelNo | type   | COUNT(*) |
+---------+--------+----------+
|       1 | single |       14 |
|       6 | double |       10 |
|       1 | vip    |        4 |
+---------+--------+----------+
```

3 rows in set (0.001 sec)

I want to get an output showing which hotelNo's have more than two double rooms.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want hotels that have more than 1 double room. I would suggest filtering on `type = 'double'`, aggregating by `hotelno`, and using a `having` clause to ensure that there is more than one record in the group:

```
select hotelno
from room
where type = 'double'
group by hotelno
having count(*) > 1
```